# Gsheets VLOOKUP returning multiple values

Tags: google-sheets, text, concatenation, vlookup

I have this sheet:

| refid | customerid | invoiceno |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5756588282 | 5364889 | 63849050 |
| 5756588282 | 5364889 | 62227291 |
| 5756588282 | 5364889 | 60565767 |
| 5756588303 | 5765682 | 62724304 |
| 5756588303 | 4137278 | 62721119 |
| 5756588303 | 4480623 | 62725914 |
| 5756587180 | 1737070 | 66385042 |
| 5756587180 | 1737070 | 66219284 |
| 5756587579 | 3008601 | 64004057 |
| 5756587579 | 3008601 | 62358070 |

I need to do a vlookup with the refid and move in the other sheet the customerid and invoiceno but I only get the first row. I need to go back here, highlight duplicates and for each refid copy/paste the customerid and invoiceno in the other sheet. This can be automated.

What is a formula that gives me all the customerid and invoiceno where the refid matches? I've tried with a textjoin and a query but I can't make it work.

What I need to achieve in the other sheet:

refid - customerid - invoiceno

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect justified by reference to authoritative documentation or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) [mre] PS It doesn't matter if it's not easy for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something alone these lines perhaps:

[image]

Formula in `G2`:

```
={TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,FILTER(B2:B;A2:A=E2)),TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,FILTER(C2:C,A2:A=E2))}
```

This will now spill both

Comment: thanks for the idea @JvdV however that's exactly what I'm doing manually, highlight the duplicates in the refid and copy/paste cust and inv on the other sheet.

What I'm trying to achieve is something more automated, like a vlookup that gives me multiple values instead of only the first row.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: @JvdV yep, but that I can do it with the duplicates as well, I've added a screenshot of what I need to achieve in the other sheet, hope it's more clear now! Thanks again

Comment: thanks a lot man, that's exactly what I needed, you saved me a lot of manual work!

Comment: Hey @JvdV quick question, if I drag down the formula it'll keep populating the rows with the same ref id decreasing the number of customerid and invoiceno.. is there a way to avoid this? it's a bit messy to locate and select only the first line etc.. 
Thanks a lot for you help!

Comment: See new pic in the description for references!

Comment: @Matt, try `={INDEX(UNIQUE(A$2:A),ROW(A1)),TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,FILTER(B$2:B,A$2:A=INDEX(UNIQUE(A$2:A),ROW(A1)))),TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,FILTER(C$2:C,A$2:A=INDEX(UNIQUE(A$2:A),ROW(A1))))}` and see if it helps you if you drag that down.

Comment: Hey @JvdV unfortunately it doesn't work, it gives me all the duplicates inside the same cell :(
See pic for reference

Comment: @Matt, worked fine for me with given sample data as per [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RZVM.png) screenshot.

Comment: Hey @JvdV damn you're right sorry, I was putting the formula on the wrong column.. sorry for the back and forth.. and thanks a lot for all your help :) much appreciated